# What is the number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{10}\times \mathbb{Z}_{25}\to S_4$?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

> What is the number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{10}\times \mathbb{Z}_{25}\to S_4$

From searching similar questions I know that if $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{10}\times \mathbb{Z}_{25}\to S_4$ is a homomorphism then the order of $\phi(x)$ divides the order of $x$, but I fail to see how to apply this here. I also know $\mathbb{Z}_{10}\times \mathbb{Z}_{25}$ is not a cyclic group.

Hints, answers are appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: In general, if there are $a$ homomorphisms from $G$ to $K$ and $b$ homomorphisms from $H$ to $K$, how many homomorphisms are there from $G\times H$ to $K$?

Comment: I have not seen this result but my best guess would be $ab$? I would not know how to show it though

Comment: Your guess is correct, and I recommend thinking about how to prove it—it will be really instructive!

Comment: If the domain of $\varphi$ is a cyclic group, then in order to classify all homomorphisms, it's sufficient to describe all possible images of $1$, namely, $\varphi(1)$. Also note that if $f: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism and $x \in G$, then the order of $f(x)$ must be a divisor of the order of $x$. Once you have described the homomorphisms $\psi: Z_{n} \rightarrow S_{4}$ for $n = 10, 25$, then apply the proposition from the comment above.